# Ошибка в unity: Invalid keystore format

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я пытался построить игру, на android в unity, но получаю ошибку, что можно сделать? Вот участок логов:

```
stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\gelse\.android\debug.keystore": Invalid keystore format

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в keys. Нужно перейти в билдере в:
Player Settings > Publishing settings > Project Keystore
После, кликнуть по Custom Keystore и создать свой Keystore, в полях можно вводить все что угодно.